# Delphi Tokyo Version Info migration from dproj

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, project-settings

I am migrating a Delphi XE codebase to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.  I cannot get project settings, particularly version info, to migrate correctly.

Based on several posts, I tried the following steps:

- deleting the `.dproj` file
- opening the `.dpr` file directly
- manually re-adding all of my options in the IDE.
- I also deleted a really old `.dof` file that was leftover from a previous Delphi 7 migration.

After opening the `.dpr` file, I set about updating options.  I ONLY made changes to **"All configurations - 32 bit Windows Platform"**.

[image]

Version changes propagated to the 32 bit release correctly...

[image]

But the version changes did not *entirely* propagate to the 32 bit debug...

[image]

Is there some workaround to get version changes to propagate from base to both release and debug?  I would like to avoid continually updating `.dproj` outside the IDE.  They get big and complex quickly.

Comment: My experience is also that something isn't quite right in this dialog.

Comment: Good practice would to disregard this, and set the version and other such information post-build. I too have many frustrations with this particular screen.

Comment: Have you [filed a bug report](http://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero? Version Info management has been pretty broken for a long time.

Comment: I use a Version.RC file after having lost too many hours to this nonsense.

Comment: The IDE's version management has been broken for many years. There are many existing posts about it here, and the consensus of all of them is that trying to use it is futile. Instead, use a pre-build event and manage it yourself with a resource file. Again, there are several previous posts here about ways to do so. A search here for `[delphi] versioninfo.rc` turns up a few examples.

Comment: @Remy, thank you for the suggestion, I have filed a bug report.  https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19662

Comment: this might help: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/